# How to surround a particular key's value with quotes in an invalid JSON document

Tags: python-2.7, sed

I would like to be able to surround all instances of a particular key's value with quotes within an invalid JSON file.

For example, if I had either of the following:

```
{
"Hour": 09
"Bla" : 2400
"Bleh" : "09"
}

or
{
"hour": 07
"Bla" : 2400
"Bleh" : "09"
}
```

I would like

```
{
"Hour": "09"
"Bla" : 2400
"Bleh" : "09"
}

or
{
"hour": "07"
"Bla" : 2400
"Bleh" : "09"
}
```

The reason I am doing this is so I can load this file into a python program and work with it; however, 09, is considered invalid json and cannot be read using python's json module.

Thanks

Comment: jq accepts numbers beginning with zeroes and automatically converts them to valid numbers. like `echo '{"hour":09}' | jq` outputs `{"hour":9}`

Comment: That looks useful. I will try it out! Thanks

Comment: If `sed s'/[0-9][0-9]*/"&"/'` isn't all you need then edit your question to provide a more truly representative example.

Comment: I edited  the example to make it more representative. Thanks for the suggestion, Ed.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd', by gnu sed

```
 sed -E '/\{/ {n;s/^("\w+":\s*)(\S+)/\1"\2"/}' d
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22739277)